# Django: Send Array from Template to View

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-views

script

```
 function submition(){
        var result=finalaproduct;
        alert(result)
        $.ajax({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
            type: "POST",
            url: "cart_in",
            data: result,
            success: function() {
                alert("SUCCESS")
        }

        });

    }
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cart_in/(?P<qid>\w+)/$', cart_in ,name='cart_in'),
```

views.py

```
def cart_in(request, qid):
    id = qid
    print(id)
    return redirect('/')
```

array i want to pass

```
[{"quantity":"36","customer_ID_id":1,"shop_ID_id":1,"product_ID_id":1},
 {"quantity":"3","customer_ID_id":1,"shop_ID_id":1,"product_ID_id":2}]
```

I want to pass array mentioned above from 'template' to 'views.py', and i got stuck while doing this.I might be following the wrong way for this.
Help me with this.

Comment: What went wrong? You are not even trying to read that post data.

Comment: how do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

script

```
   function submition(){
        var result=finalaproduct;
        alert(result)
        $.ajax({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": '{{csrf_token}}' },
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cart_in/",
            data:{"content": result},
            success:function(){
                alert("Data recieved")
            }

        });

    }
```

views.py

```
def cart_in(request,qid,*args,**kwargs):
   data = request.POST['content']
   print(type(data))
   pass
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cart_in/(?P<qid>\w+)/$', cart_in ,name='cart_in'),
url(r'^cart_in/', cart_in ,name='cart_in'),
```

This will work.
with or without id.